# How I can resolve currency code error for Paypal NVP CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile call?

Tags: paypal

> And where my receiver country is India and sender country is us.

````
                multiValueMap.add("VERSION", "86");
                multiValueMap.add("USER", "xx");
                multiValueMap.add("PWD", "xxx");
                multiValueMap.add("SIGNATURE", "***");
                multiValueMap.add("TOKEN", token);
                multiValueMap.add("PAYERID", payerID);
                multiValueMap.add("PROFILESTARTDATE", "22-09-2019");
                multiValueMap.add("DESC", "Charges");
                multiValueMap.add("BILLINGPERIOD", "Month");
                multiValueMap.add("BILLINGFREQUENCY", "1");
                multiValueMap.add("AMT", price);
                multiValueMap.add("CURRENCYCODE", "USD");
                multiValueMap.add("COUNTRYCODE", "US");```
````

Comment: Please, help me. Already I raised the question on PayPal community and from the merchant account. No response I get from them.

Comment: If there is any problem with my PayPal settings, please suggest me.